# How can I get the timezone in typescript

Tags: typescript, date

I cannot find any function to get the timezone as string in typescript, like 'Europe/Berlin'

The Date class can just show me the timezoneOffset

Comment: No, like I said, I know, that there is a funtion to get the offset. But I need to timezone name as a string.

Comment: The linked duplicate has answers to both. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602679/14637).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment js and moment-timezone are in maintenance mode. it support most of Browser. It's not dead so you can still use it.

However it has some limitation like Tree shaking - reduce build size by import function as per need.

1. [Luxon js](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones) - enhanced version of moment.js which have tree shaking and other advantages.

   ```
   DateTime.local().zoneName;

   Output: America/Chicago
   ```
2. You can still use moment-timezone as mention here.
   https://momentjs.com/timezone/

   Below method will give you clients timezone in the format you needs.

   ```
   moment.tz.guess();

   Output: America/Chicago
   ```

Here is an other alternative way similar to moment js.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/

Comment: Please don't recommend momentjs, it's considered legacy. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: Luxon is a better alternative

Comment: Momentjs is in maintenance mode. This is copied directly from their GitHub https://github.com/moment/moment/ Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases, you should choose a different library.

Comment: Updated answer based on latest lib status changes.